# Hearthstone Heroes of Warcraft not downloading iOS

Tags: ios, hearthstone

So I decided to download Hearthstone HoW on my iPhone 5c recently, and it takes up 778 MB. I have ~990 space available, and the app installs normally, but when there is ~1 MB left of download, it says that it cannot be installed at this time, I click "Retry" and then it says I have no space left even though I have more than enough space. Please help!

iOS 8.1-8.2, 16 GB Max space, iPhone 5c,
Hearthstone HoW not downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Hearthstone - Heroes of Warcraft actually takes up 1.2GB and you said that you have 990 MB I'm assuming. That might be the problem.